# 100 тысяч рублей за моральный вред и опровержение - два назывных предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

Ситуация, описываемая в статье, такова: некий истец требует взыскать с ответчика 100 тысяч рублей в качестве компенсации морального вреда, а также требует опровержения сведений.

Заголовок статьи:

*100 тысяч рублей за моральный вред и опровержение*

Правильно ли будет рассматривать предложение в этом заголовке как сложное с двумя назывными, или это неполное предложение с пропущенным сказуемым "требуют"?

(Требуют) 100 тысяч рублей за моральный вред и опровержение.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, это конструкция, соответствующая сложному предложению с двумя назывными. В конце концов у заголовка основная функция номинативная, если бы здесь приоритетной была информация о том, что кто-то что-то требует, это тоже было бы в заголовке, здесь же глагола нет, значит, он  и не нужен, важно указать на предмет обсуждения.